# CMAC Algorithm with Blowfish instead of AES

Tags: lua, cryptography, blowfish, cmac

**Background**

I have an Lua Environment which has the blowfish crypto (CBC, IV = {00..0}) builtin. AES is not available and pure Lua AES-Implementations are way to slow.

**Problem**

I want to generate a CMAC according to the algorithm specified in [RFC 4493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4493), which is AES based. As I need this CMAC for exchange between the Lua environment and another program built by myself, I thought I just change all AES crypt functions to Blowfish ones.

The input length for each CMAC is 26 Byte, whereas only a few bytes change between different CMAC generations. For example:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA BA AACCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
AAAAAAAAAAAA AB AACCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

which results in the problem, that the first part of the CMAC is identical for each input and only the last part changes:

```
0123456789ABCDEF 48534593402BC93D
0123456789ABCDEF DF82BC920DA92383
```

Is this a problem of the blowfish algorithm? Is there anything I can do (change the CMAC algo) to ensure, that I get different results, especially with only small changes to the input?

Comment: The blowfish algorithm is fine, and should generate bytes indistinguishable from random to an attacker (that does not know the key, of course). Each identical block will encrypt to the same value for the same key. This is OK, as the CMAC construction should still generate indistinguishable authentication tags even if the supplied data is different by one bit. In other words, your implementation is faulty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design CMAC can be used with 64-bit block ciphers such as Blowfish. But the output will also be 64 bit.
You should not change anything in the algorithm.
See http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/SP_800-38B.pdf for reference.
Also note that the security of 64bit MACs is quite low.

Comment: +1 the NIST specification should be used for this, not the AES specific one as described in the RFC.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. I didn't take the block size into account. The NIST specification details implementation for 64-bit block ciphers as well, so I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on [CMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC) has an explanation of the algorithm.

AES is a 128-bit block cipher while Blowfish is a 64-bit block cipher. Several parts of the CMAC algorithm depend on the block size. You'll have to rewrite those parts.

In general, it's not a good idea to implement cryptographic algorithms yourself; many subtle things can go wrong. Lua might not be a good choice for writing an application that uses cryptography if there are no cryptography libraries available.

Comment: I know that Lua is not a good choice in this situation. Sadly I need to work with a provided lua environment (it's not under my control). The only implemented algo is blowfish. I see now, that the blocksize is fixed to 16 Byte in the CMAC algorithm. I would need to change this to 8 Byte, to use Blowfish, right? The algorithm should be used for key diversification [see NXP documentation](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10922.pdf). Looking at section 2.4, using 2TDEA (which is 64-bit block cipher as well),  should I use this instead of the original AES-128 algorithm?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea. The inner workings of cryptographic algorithms are complex, and complexity is the enemy of security. Do you have access to SHA-256? If you do, you might be better off with the much simpler [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Comment: Actually, you might even get away with HMAC-MD5, since the weaknesses of MD5 don't apply to HMAC.